# Where can I find the default location for android keystores created by eclipse?

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, keystore

I can't remember which file location I chose when exporting my signed android application via Android Tools in Eclipse on Fedora 15 and JDK 6.

I only do find a "debug.keystore" file at ~/.android/, but my android app is already in the Android Market. Is it possible I uploaded an apk with a debug keystore ?

Is that maybe because I used:

"right click on my eclipse project" -> "Android Tools" -> "Export Signed Android Application".

Instead of:

"File" -> "Export" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My private keystore actually was the "debug.**keystore**" which can be found at: **~/.android/**.

I just gave it the misleading name "debug".

Answer (score 1):

The default location is the same where your android SDK is stored, in my case (having installed the android SDK via macports) it is `/opt/local/share/java`.

Answer (score 0):

If there was a helpful default location you could just go through the export process and be looking at the right place already. I'll assume you tried that and your keystore wasn't there, in which case you'll need to find it yourself. If you remember even a portion of the file name (like perhaps it ends in .keystore), you can try the `locate` command, such as `locate keystore`.

Comment: The Problem is I only do find a "debug.keystore" file at ~/.android/, but my android app is already in the Android Market.

Is it possible I uploaded an apk with a debug keystore?